# Updating existing excel document with Apache POI via Groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, apache-poi

I am trying to update an existing excel document with via Groovy Script. I have tried with jxl, but the file was always corrupted so as I was suggested I have tried with Apache POI. I have found the code that I have managed to configure that looks like so:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Path.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");

            // index from 0,0... cell A1 is cell(0,0)
            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);

            HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
            cellA1.setCellValue("Hello");
            HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.createCell((short) 1);
            cellB1.setCellValue("Goodbye");
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellB1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.createCell((short) 2);
            cellC1.setCellValue(true);

            HSSFCell cellD1 = row1.createCell((short) 3);
            cellD1.setCellValue(new Date());
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat
                    .getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
            cellD1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

              fileOut.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("Path.xls"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();
```

The code works perfectly and I am having the fields defined written in the file, but the problem is that with the current code all previous data is deleted ... I have tried to preserve the data but without any success.

Can you tell me how I can make the update of the document without deleting the previous data?

Comment: Use `getRow()` rather than `createRow()` ?

Comment: If i use  `HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet")` or `HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow((short) 0)` I am getting **java.lang.NullPointerExceptiion: Cannnot invoke method getRow() on null object.** I guess I need to alter the first couple of rows where I am defining the document, but I don't know how :(

Comment: Try and fetch the row, use the existing one if it is defined, and create a new one if not?